How to create a template that uses an existing class A as parameter a keeps an instance of class A as non-copyable and non-assignable?
How to create a template that uses an existing class A as parameter a keeps an instance of class A as non-copyable and non-assignable?
I would like to create that template to prevents one from accidentially copying the class like protected prevents one from accidentially accessing and like const prevents one from accidentially modifying.
Here's a simplified version of what I'm aiming for:
NonCopyable<std::vector<int>> vec1{1, 2, 3};
NonCopyable<std::vector<int>> vec2(vec1);    // should not compile
vec2 = vec1;                                 // should not compile

What would be an appropriate template APPROACH to achieve this behavior, assuming I only can take the original class as is and don't want to derive from that class?
NOTE: This question was inspired by How to make an existing class non-copyable and non-assignable using a template without inheritance?. This question refines the earlier one with more details clarifying the question I believe have been asked.

Regarding your "NOTE", it would be more politic to phrase the note as crediting the earlier question for inspiring yours. Especially since you blatantly copied someone else's writing. Something less confrontational and more along the lines of "This question was inspired by X. This question refines the earlier one with more details clarifying the question I believe should have been asked." (Of course, rephrase to be accurate, but I encourage a diplomatic mindset.)

JaMiT, agreed - for the most of it - not the "blatantly copied" thing. I like your suggestion regarding a change of the text. Hence, I have change it accordingly. In turn, I also encourage a helping mindset - which I couldn't see in all of the comments and down votes in the referenced post. Thank you for you diplomacy here.

"not the 'blatantly copied' thing" -- I guess that is subjective terminology. Let me put it more objectively. Not counting your "NOTE" (which now serves to credit the source), 46% of the words (outside the code block) and 100% of the code in your question matches the other question. Also, 45% of the words (outside the code block) and 100% of the code in the other question matches your question. That is enough to justify someone thinking "plagiarism" if the source is not credited, even if someone else thinks it falls below the threshold for "blatant" copying.

Thank you for crediting that this may fall below the threshold, @JaMiT. Objectivity is your thing that I can learn from - honestly. I have seen some of your answers. You are a good one. Let have a chat together at SO some-when to stop this arguing and let's help together. Thank you.

First of all: There is no such template that prevents one from copying data against all counter effort that one can make.
Code
Here, is the code of template class being a wrapper as a starting point to prevent accidental copying using copy constructors or copy operators.
#include    <vector>

template< typename T >
struct NonCopyable
{
private:
    T   value;
public:
    NonCopyable( const NonCopyable<T>& t ) noexcept = delete;
    NonCopyable( NonCopyable<T>& t ) noexcept = delete;
    NonCopyable( NonCopyable<T>&& t ) noexcept = delete;
    template< typename... Targs >
    NonCopyable( const Targs... args ) noexcept : value{ args... } {
    }
    operator T&() const = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = ( const NonCopyable& ) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = ( NonCopyable& ) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = ( NonCopyable&& ) = delete;
};

int main( [[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]]char* argv[] ) {
    NonCopyable< std::vector<int> > vec1{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    //NonCopyable< std::vector<int> > vec2( vec1 );     // would lead to the following compiler error:
    /*
    src/test2_2.cpp:25:48: error: use of deleted function ‘NonCopyable<T>::NonCopyable(NonCopyable<T>&) [with T = std::vector<int>]’
    25 |     NonCopyable< std::vector<int> > vec2( vec1 );   // should not compile
        |                                                ^
    */
    //vec2 = vec1;                                      // would lead to the following compiler error:
    /*
    src/test2_2.cpp:31:12: error: use of deleted function ‘NonCopyable<T>& NonCopyable<T>::operator=(NonCopyable<T>&) [with T = std::vector<int>]’
    31 |     vec2 = vec1;
        |            ^~~~
    */
    return 0;
}

Disclaimer
As such, the template has no use but can be enriched with interfaces that accesses the value. See the example below. Please, also consider the more information is exposed the easier it may become possible to deduce the value and hence make it possible to create a copy.
Example to access the value
Assuming, it is considered sufficient to protect against accidental usage of copying and having a generic interface access the value. The following solution is an example to process the value.
#include    <vector>
#include    <functional>
#include    <iostream>

template< typename T >
struct NonCopyable
{
private:
    T   value;
public:
    NonCopyable( const NonCopyable<T>& t ) noexcept = delete;
    NonCopyable( NonCopyable<T>& t ) noexcept = delete;
    NonCopyable( NonCopyable<T>&& t ) noexcept = delete;
    template< typename... Targs >
    NonCopyable( const Targs... args ) noexcept : value{ args... } {
    }
    operator T&() const = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = ( const NonCopyable& ) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = ( NonCopyable& ) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = ( NonCopyable&& ) = delete;
    template<class TReturn>
    TReturn process( std::function<TReturn(const T&)> f ) {
        return f( value );
    }

};

int main( [[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]]char* argv[] ) {
    typedef std::vector<int>  IntVec;
    NonCopyable< IntVec >   vec1{ 2, 3, 5 };
    double average = vec1.template process<double>( 
            []( const IntVec& vn ) {
                        int     nSum = 0;
                        int     nCount = 0;
                        for ( auto& n : vn ) {
                            nSum += n;
                            nCount++;
                        }
                        return double( nSum ) / double ( nCount );
            }
        );
    std::cout << "average = " << average << std::endl;

    //NonCopyable< std::vector<int> > vec2( vec1 );     // would lead to the following compiler error:
    /*
    src/test2_2.cpp:45:48: error: use of deleted function ‘NonCopyable<T>::NonCopyable(NonCopyable<T>&) [with T = std::vector<int>]’
    45 |     NonCopyable< std::vector<int> > vec2( vec1 );     // would lead to the following compiler error:
        |                                                ^
    src/test2_2.cpp:13:5: note: declared here
    13 |     NonCopyable( NonCopyable<T>& t ) noexcept = delete;
        |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
    */
    //vec2 = vec1;                                      // would lead to the following compiler error:
    /*
    src/test2_2.cpp:54:12: error: use of deleted function ‘NonCopyable<T>& NonCopyable<T>::operator=(NonCopyable<T>&) [with T = std::vector<int>]’
    54 |     vec2 = vec1;                                      // would lead to the following compiler error:
        |            ^~~~
    src/test2_2.cpp:20:18: note: declared here
    20 |     NonCopyable& operator = ( NonCopyable& ) = delete;
        |                  ^~~~~~~~
    */
    return 0;
}

Output:
average = 3.33333

NOTE: As disclaimed earlier, now someone can inject a function to copy the value.
Example with using inheritance internally
#include    <vector>
#include    <functional>
#include    <iostream>

template< typename T >
class NonCopyable : public T 
{
public:
    NonCopyable( const NonCopyable<T>& t ) noexcept = delete;
    NonCopyable( NonCopyable<T>& t ) noexcept = delete;
    NonCopyable( NonCopyable<T>&& t ) noexcept = delete;
    template< typename... Targs >
    NonCopyable( const Targs... args ) noexcept : T{ args... } {
    }
    operator T&() const = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = ( const NonCopyable& ) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = ( NonCopyable& ) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = ( NonCopyable&& ) = delete;
    template<class TReturn>
    TReturn process( std::function<TReturn(const T&)> f ) {
        return f( *this );
    }

};

int main( [[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]]char* argv[] ) {
    typedef std::vector<int>  IntVec;
    NonCopyable< IntVec >   vec1{ 2, 3, 5 };
    vec1.push_back( 7 );
    double average = vec1.template process<double>( 
            []( const IntVec& vn ) {
                        int     nSum = 0;
                        int     nCount = 0;
                        for ( auto& n : vn ) {
                            nSum += n;
                            nCount++;
                        }
                        return double( nSum ) / double ( nCount );
            }
        );
    std::cout << "average = " << average << std::endl;

    //NonCopyable< std::vector<int> > vec2( vec1 ); // would lead to the following compiler error:
    /*
    src/test2_3.cpp:44:48: error: use of deleted function ‘NonCopyable<T>::NonCopyable(NonCopyable<T>&) [with T = std::vector<int>]’
    44 |     NonCopyable< std::vector<int> > vec2( vec1 );     // would lead to the following compiler error:
        |                                                ^
    src/test2_3.cpp:11:5: note: declared here
    11 |     NonCopyable( NonCopyable<T>& t ) noexcept = delete;
        |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
    */
    //NonCopyable< IntVec > vec2 = vec1; // would lead to the following compiler error:
    /*
    src/test2_3.cpp:53:27: error: redeclaration of ‘NonCopyable<std::vector<int> > vec2’
    53 |     NonCopyable< IntVec > vec2 = vec1;                                      // would lead to the following compiler error:
        |                           ^~~~
    src/test2_3.cpp:44:37: note: ‘NonCopyable<std::vector<int> > vec2’ previously declared here
    44 |     NonCopyable< std::vector<int> > vec2( vec1 );     // would lead to the following compiler error:
        |                                     ^~~~
    */
    return 0;
}

Output:
average = 4.25

Final word
The asked and presented approach prevents from accidental copying ("non-copyable and non-assignable").
I consider such means as legitimate as protected value prevents direct access and is still modifiable in a derived class, and in the same way this applies to keyword const.
This answer has originally been posted at
How to make an existing class non-copyable and non-assignable using a template without inheritance? but moved for special reasons.
Compatibility
NOTE: All the code has been compiled with -std=c++20 and -std=c++11.
